# How do you create a dynamic QueryDSL operator based on a quoted String value

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have a pojo that contains a property name, logic operator as String and the value of property. What I want to accomplish is create a Predicate or Expression etc dynamically from the pojo data. Below are my code:

```
public class QueryParam {
    private String property = "acctType";   //can be any property of classname
    private String operator = "eqic"        //can be any logic operator !=, >, <, >=, <= etc
    private Object value;                   //will store the value of 

    // getters/setters here
}

public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Customer>{

}

@Service("CustomerService")
class MyCustomerServiceImpl {
    @Resource
    private CustomerRepository custRpstry;

    //if classname is Customer, property is "acctType", operator is "eqic", and value is "Corporate"
    //I want my findAll below to retrieve all Customers having acctType = "Corporate"
    List<Customer> findAll(List<QueryParam> qryParam) {
        QCustomer qcust = QCustomer.customer;

        BooleanBuilder where = new BooleanBuilder();
        for(QueryParam param : qryParam) {

            //within this block, i want a BooleanBuilder to resolve to:
            where.and(qcust.acctType.equalsIgnoreCase("Corporate"));

            something like:
            where.and(param.getClassname().param.getProperty().param.getOperator().param.getValue())
        }

        return custRpstry.findAll(where.getValue()).getContent();

    }
}
```

I can't figure out to formulate my BooleanBuilder especially the portion that will convert
getOperator() into .equalIgnoreCase().

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Mario

Answer (score 2):

After combining several answers to some related questions here in so, I was able to formulate a solution that works for me.

```
BooleanBuilder where = new BooleanBuilder();
for(QueryParam param: qryParam) {
    //create: Expressions.predicate(Operator<Boolean> opr, StringPath sp, filter value)

    //create an Operator<Boolean>
    Operator<Boolean> opr = OperationUtils.getOperator(param.getOperator().getValue());

    //create a StringPath to a class' property
    Path<User> entityPath = Expressions.path(Customer.class, "customer");
    Path<String> propPath = Expressions.path(String.class, entityPath, param.getProperty());

    //create Predicate expression
    Predicate predicate = Expressions.predicate(opr, propPath, Expressions.constant(param.getValue()));
    where.and(predicate);
}

list = repository.findAll(where.getValue(), pageReq).getContent();
```

My OperationUtils.java

```
public class OperationUtils {

    public static com.mysema.query.types.Operator<Boolean> getOperator(String key) {
        Map<String, com.mysema.query.types.Operator<Boolean>> operators = ImmutableMap.<String, com.mysema.query.types.Operator<Boolean>>builder()
                  .put(Operator.EQ.getValue()   ,Ops.EQ)
                  .put(Operator.NE.getValue()   ,Ops.NE)
                  .put(Operator.GT.getValue()   ,Ops.GT)
                  .put(Operator.GTE.getValue()  ,Ops.GOE)
                  .put(Operator.LT.getValue()   ,Ops.LT)
                  .put(Operator.LTE.getValue()  ,Ops.LOE)
                  .build();

        return operators.get(key);
    }
}
```